# Create AutoCAD .dwg file online (on server) without opening AutoCAD with C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocad, autodesk, dwg

I managed to create and manipulate with AutoCAD files with this library (wpf app)

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-with-autocad/

Found it in this post

- [Create Autocad file with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015665/create-autocad-file-with-c-sharp)

Howewer, to use this library, AutoCAD has to be opened (window visible) while program does coded drawing.

This is fairly old post (5 years) so the rest of it does not fulfill my wishes. And maybe during this 5 years something came up.

Does anyone know is it possible and how to create and/or manipulate .dwg files on server using asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Forge Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/), which is basically an instance of AutoCAD running on the cloud where you can upload DWG files along with custom code (e.g. .NET DLL) and a script (sequence of commands). At the end, you can download the results.

Comment: I will check it, thank you... it might be the thing I was searching for